# gamm4 what does s() do?

Tags: r, gamm4

say we have the following:

```
library(gamm4)
    set.seed(0)
    dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,scale=2) ## simulate 4 term additive truth
    ## Now add 20 level random effect fac...
    dat$fac <- fac <- as.factor(sample(1:20,400,replace=TRUE))
        dat$y <- dat$y + model.matrix(~fac-1)%*%rnorm(20)*.5
gamm4 5
    br <- gamm4(y~s(x0)+x1+s(x2),data=dat,random=~(1|fac))
```

What does the `s()` do in this model?

Comment: it just mean you only estimate the intercept and not the slope>?

Comment: it is a function used in the definition of smooth terms within gam(m) model formulae. See `?mgcv::s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(gamm4)
    set.seed(0)
    dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,scale=2) ## simulate 4 term additive truth
    ## Now add 20 level random effect fac...
    dat$fac <- fac <- as.factor(sample(1:20,400,replace=TRUE))
            dat$y <- dat$y + model.matrix(~fac-1)%*%rnorm(20)*.5
    #gamm4 5
        br <- gamm4(y~s(x0)+x1+s(x2),data=dat,random=~(1|fac))
    plot(br$gam,pages=1,all=TRUE)
    br <- gamm4(y~x0+x1+x2,data=dat,random=~(1|fac))
plot(br$gam,pages=1,all=TRUE)
```

`s()` terms are represented as penalized splines.  You might read Simon Wood's 2006 textbook for more on what that is.  The code above illustrates the difference with and without.